# 2.x,3.x iOS static build: Fatal Python error: exceptions bootstrapping error

Tags: python, ios

I trying to make minimal part of Python to work as part (static library) of my iOS application for internal scripting. I used configure under Mac OS X(10.7) and it was successful. Then I got compilable and linkable XCode project very fast.
The problem is, when I trying to use Python by

```
Py_NoSiteFlag=1;
Py_Initialize();
```

it fails with error "Fatal Python error: exceptions bootstrapping error." inside _PyExc_Init().
I tried to debug it, but unfortunately I cant understand why it fails. May be bacause I noob in Python source, but anyway, I need to port it. Tried 2.7.3, or 3.2.3, it was the same result as above. Any solution or hint will be very helpful.

Call stack:

```
#0        0x300cba1c in __pthread_kill ()
#1        0x362e43ba in pthread_kill ()
#2        0x362dcbfe in abort ()
#3        0x00127d96 in Py_FatalError at /Users/mac_user/Downloads/Python-3.2.3/IOS/pythoncore/../../Python/pythonrun.c:2169
#4        0x00155328 in _PyExc_Init at /Users/mac_user/Downloads/Python-3.2.3/IOS/pythoncore/../../Objects/exceptions.c:2042
#5        0x00127ad4 in Py_InitializeEx at /Users/mac_user/Downloads/Python-3.2.3/IOS/pythoncore/../../Python/pythonrun.c:272
#6        0x0012846a in Py_Initialize at /Users/mac_user/Downloads/Python-3.2.3/IOS/pythoncore/../../Python/pythonrun.c:332
#7        0x000d6242 in testpython at /Users/mac_user/Downloads/Python-3.2.3/IOS/test/test/testmac.c:15
#8        0x000d618e in -[ViewController viewDidLoad] at /Users/mac_user/Downloads/Python-3.2.3/IOS/test/test/ViewController.m:23
#9        0x3283ff0e in -[UIViewController view] ()
#10        0x3283e2b4 in -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] ()
#11        0x3283a332 in -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] ()
#12        0x3283e28e in -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] ()
#13        0x3284cc60 in -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] ()
#14        0x000d5ffe in -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] at /Users/mac_user/Downloads/Python-3.2.3/IOS/test/test/AppDelegate.m:35
#15        0x3283e820 in -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] ()
#16        0x32838b64 in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] ()
#17        0x3280d7d6 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] ()
#18        0x3280d214 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#19        0x3280cc52 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#20        0x322b7e76 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#21        0x3113ba96 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#22        0x3113d83e in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not wrap your non-code text in `<pre>` (and for code, use the 4-space-indent markdown syntax). Actually you rarely need to use HTML at all - see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1. The error you're getting is from a failing to import builtins module.

   From http://hg.python.org/releasing/3.2.3/file/86d1421a552c/Objects/exceptions.c

   ```
   2040     bltinmod = PyImport_ImportModule("builtins");   
   2041     if (bltinmod == NULL)
   2042         Py_FatalError("exceptions bootstrapping error.");
   ```

   You can follow the code up from there, and there are lots of reasons why
   this import could fail. If you want to know what's actually wrong, you'll
   need to step through it.
2. Or, you could check this out:

   https://github.com/cobbal/python-for-iphone

   "Build script for compiling python into a static library that can be used with the official SDK"

Comment: Thank You! About solution 1. I tried look as deep as I can. The result from 3.2.3 port: it fails in Python/getargs.c:convertsimple():line 709, error "signed integer is less than minimum". It parses some parameters, and we have an error on last, 5th parameter. I really have no idea what happens here and why, knowing that same code works just fine under Windows. Solution 2: I'll try it, but my final target is port current latest 2.x(2.7.3) to iOS, so 2.6.5 is old for my application. Tried 3.x that time just for "what if? maybe 3.x will work, or,...".

Comment: Finally I tried solution 2. Simulator configure failed, but when I commented this out, and fixed all for new iOS / Xcode, I got working Python 2.6.5 static library. I'll try to fix build script to get the same for 2.7.

Comment: 2.7 is also worked with script from https://github.com/cobbal/python-for-iphone using patch from http://randomsplat.com/id5-cross-compiling-python-for-embedded-linux.html